# How to detect that code is executed in design-time?

Tags: .net, activereports

ActiveReports 10 Extension for Visual Studio have designer for reports.
Designer windows contains tab "Preview" where designer report can be viewed without running whole application

I want create "testing" data which will be used only in design-time.
Setting data in the code works fine.

```vb
Private Sub TestReport_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart
  Me.DataSource = TestModule.GetData() ' - Test data
  'Me.DataSource = _MyDataService.GetData() ' - Production data
End Sub
```

But after working with reports you need to remember remove testing data and set "production" code, which very easily can be forgotten.

It seems like "Preview"-code executing in run-time mode, see used testing code below

```vb
Private Sub TestReport_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart
    Dim isDebug As Boolean = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached 'Return false
    Dim mode As LicenseUsageMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode 'Return Runtime       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and tests I came up with two solutions for that problem.

**Solution 1** - `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`
From MSDN:

> Gets the process executable in the default application domain. In
>   other application domains, this is the first executable that was
>   executed by AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly.

Seems like "Preview" not running in the default application domain and ActiveReports not calling `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly()`. So method `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` will return `null`

```vb
Public Class TestReport

    Private _DataService As IDataService

    Public Sub New(dataService As IDataService)
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        _DataService = dataService
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart
        If Me.IsDesignMode = True Then
            Me.DataSource = TestModule.GetData()
        Else
            Me.DataSource = _DataService.GetData()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected ReadOnly Property IsDesignMode As Boolean
        Get
            Return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() Is Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

**Solution 2** - Parameterless constructor
- Report class use interface `IDataService` for getting data.
- Create implementation of `IDataService` which return testing data
- Create parameterless constructor where original constructor which takes instance of `IDataService` will be called with instance of testing implementation of interface as parameter.
- Mark parameterless constructor with `Obsolete` attribute to tell other developers not use it
- Optional: use first solution here and throw exception if test data service was using in the run-time

```vb
Public Class TestReport

    Private _DataService As IDataService

    Public Sub New(dataService As IDataService)
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        _DataService = dataService
    End Sub

    <Obsolete("Parameterless consrtuctor only for designer usage.")>
    Public Sub New()
        MyClass.New(New TestDataService())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart
        Me.DataSource = _DataService.GetData()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TestDataService
    Implements IDataService

    Public Sub New()
        If Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Service cannot be used in run-time")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetData() As List(Of CustomItem) Implements IDataService.GetData
        'Generate test data
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work for code that will also be hosted within ASP.Net :(

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using activereports.

At this time, I do not know of a way to do this in AR10.  You might be able to control it with a config parameter in your applicaiton, similar to the isDebug setting but using an XML config instead.

Also, please email our support team http://activereports.grapecity.com and we can add a design-time report variable in a future update that you can check in your code and queries.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of using XML config?

Answer (score 0):

Fabio, i played around with this.

what I found was that LicenseUsageMode does not help. It return Runtime when previewed inside IDE and if run through the compiled exe(pure runtime so to speak).  This is becuase how the report preview code is structured.  We essentially for the most part of it take a copy of the report and load it int the viewer in preview without taking into account the license context.  that is why it gives runtime.

I also tried the usage of processname to check and when run through IDE it gives the vs exe's name: devenv which can be used but somewhat unreliable as it can be changed manually to name something else.

getEntryAssembly does return NULL when run throgh IDE, which I think is the most relaible.  I have not found any other ways, but I think there must be other ways to see that distinction.

here is the codesnippet i used in a format event of a report

// ((this as IComponent).Site == null)
            // this retursn true for both pure runtime pr previewed through designer.

```
        // use licensemode usage.
        this.textBox1.Text += "LicenseUsageMode:   " + LicenseManager.UsageMode;

        this.textBox1.Text += "\r\n";

        // getEntryassembly
        if (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == null)
            this.textBox1.Text += "GetEntryAssembly:   null";
        else
            this.textBox1.Text += "GetEntryAssembly:   NOT null";

        this.textBox1.Text += "\r\n";
        // System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe")
        this.textBox1.Text += "Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName:   ";
        this.textBox1.Text += System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName ;
        this.textBox1.Text += "\r\n";
```

this gave me:

LicenseManger value when previewed in IDE : LicenseManager.UsageMode is RunTime
LicenseManger value when previewed at pure runtime(button click for example): LicenseManager.UsageMode is RunTime

getEntryassembly value when previewed in IDE : null
getEntryassembly value when previewed at pure runtime(button click for example): NOT null

processname value when previewed in IDE : devenv.exe (somewhat unreliable as I mentioned above)
processname value when previewed at pure runtime(button click for example):  NOT devenv.exe